# TypeScript dynamically derived fields from another type

Tags: typescript

```
export type Foo = {
  a: boolean
  b: number
}
```

I'd like to create another type based on `Foo`, but add a prefix to its fields names:

```
export type Foo2 = {
  bar_a: boolean
  bar_b: number
}
```

is it possible?

Comment: If you can explicitly list all members, yes. If you want it to automatically prefix all members without listing them, currently no.

Answer (score 4):

As of TypeScript 3.5 you cannot do this programmatically.  There is an [open issue in GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754) that suggests being able to augment keys in mapped types.  If you care about this a lot, you might want to head over there and give it a  or describe your use case if you think it's more compelling than what's already in here.

---

In the meantime the only thing you can do is maintain such a mapping yourself manually.  There are lots of possible ways to implement a mapped type that transforms keys, and lots of caveats about where this goes wrong.  Mapped types are designed to transform property *values*, not *keys*, and so the tools TypeScript gives us are not perfectly suited to the task.  Still, here's one way to do it:

```
// MapKeys<T, M> takes an object type T and a key map M  and produces 
// a new type whose keys are mapped from M (or left alone if they are not in  M)
//
// Thus MapKeys<{a: 0, b: 1}, {a: "A", z: "Z"}> becomes {A: 0, b: 1}
//
// The following is one of many possible implementations. 
// It does not properly deal well with optional properties, e.g., {a?: number}
// and types with index-signature properties, e.g., {[k: string]: number}
// (these can be worked around with even more complexity)
type MapKeys<T extends object, M extends Record<keyof M, keyof any>> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: (a: { [P in K extends keyof M ? M[K] : K]: T[K] }) => void
}[keyof T] extends (a: infer U) => void
  ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] }
  : never;
```

And let's see it applied to your type:

```
export type Foo = {
  a: boolean;
  b: number;
};

type KeyMap = {
  a: "bar_a";
  b: "bar_b";
  c: "bar_c";
  d: "bad_d";
  // etc
};

export type Foo2 = MapKeys<Foo, KeyMap>;
// type Foo2 = {
//    bar_a: boolean;
//    bar_b: number;
// }
```

Looks good.  Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/PTAEFkEMAcGkFMCeBnAPAFQDQQHygC6QDW8yokAdqAPYBGAVvAMb4GLTyjrkUAm5oEolABbGBFA9+0AE7VeAVyalQAKBACK8AO5sOobQAtqyTkLKQZnMdA78AZnJESAFNRmgANvHutIn6i1QAEt7AkMkcitQCmpWYKoIAEp1YFSuQwUyKDgkNABvSAAuUAAGbFoSgEYAX2xCkoAiAEFG7AAvJoAtRpq8WmZqERV85pLy0ErQWtT09AjQe2pPAO0EgHMQskDOajCxCmFoE2Rg2m8QkWhvYYpCfGDA5AA6NQ0ASVZeahVY1llqBwZJ5hLx4P4DPAVgZgvhDDRoA9AhCAUCHqRsPBnutnvVIAB+EoUBQiAYyGrpSj8fDsFRrOEhPjwAAeAFpTusKJB8Apoqj4DJ0chMdjcaB8gBtIglZD4GQbAC6RJJZIpGhccNInCYlEmnG07hI-Es1AUfBhDPgADd4FQRO5tUNrizYYgUjT9DkECgMKAWfhbbxtgxmPhsOA-cyA3wyAAlQYyXioIR7CDYFNhSiIHB4AC84tUkglsEZgiQqfQCtZhNALmK4tAEoACqWS-7A2QMxJ8RBiwrQCVYEquH3QDUkqBc3grdRgrxVDUpeWwpXI9Gg7X6wl7ALQABVCdT0AzueF0A9-KNksJMuIVN74d70cUyRE60CgDcqlULOOgr0nAAGLUNQk4FpI9a0CB3iUF+khTMSpKfguX6qB6nDejkYH5Ge9aNLQlgAPqQI0cGTE0BEyIRtCkWeTAUURTC0ZIvAMbwhG8MxoAaPA+BMCh36-u4rDoaAwHUAATGBXp5Kg4nYJhMA4F+GiieJUn5jhGiSJMRGQdB4IUCpYA6ZR1HKkhMjGWOqhAA)