# How to type a function for renaming object keys in Typescript

Tags: typescript, object, key, rename

I have a function that takes a string transformation function and a an object and applies the transformation to all of the keys, returning the resulting object.

In particular I'm using Ramda

Here is my function (untyped for clarity).

```
const renameBy = R.curry(
  (fn, obj) => R.pipe(
      R.toPairs,
      R.map([k, v] => [fn(k), v]),
      R.fromPairs
    )(obj)
);
```

I'm well aware of the issues currying can cause, so I'm really only looking for solutions addressing the core function (and optionally the second unary function, renameBy(fn)) and resolving a nicer return type than the current R.Dictionary, which basically never matches anything.

I've been looking [here, dealing with renaming specific keys of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52702461/rename-key-of-typescript-object-type) and [here, dealing with recursive, deep nested-object renaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53124824/recursively-changing-property-names-of-a-typescript-type-including-nested-array) but neither seems to quite be what I'm looking for.

Example of usage

```
const input = {
     foo_bar: "foobar",
     bar: "bar",
     bar_foo: "barfoo"
}

const camelize = (paramName) =>
  paramName.replace(
    /_(.?)/g,
    $1 => $1.substr(1).toUpperCase()
  );

renameBy(camelize, input)

const expectedOutput = {
     fooBar: "foobar",
     bar: "bar",
     barFoo: "barfoo"
}
```

It's possible I could use something like

```
function renameBy<
     F extends (str: string) => string,
     N extends string[],
     M extends Record<string, any>
   >(fn: F, obj: M): { [P in N]: M[keyof M] }
      {...}
```

But I can't quite get it to work.

Comment: For the typing you could do [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56546038/2887218) if you can statically represent the renaming function.  But really, with `F`, all you're going to be able to do is something like `Record<ReturnType<F>, M[keyof M]>`, which is pretty wide and maybe not worth your time

Comment: [Worth it or not?](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXzlSgFsQAhATwB4AxeEADwxFWAGd4AKNjGALng8YWVAHMAlPAC8APkG8RogDTwAsvSYt28HACMAVuAwzOAKHhJUAmkvM6DA1afECASuBwxgVdxmQxUABUKAAcQWhkVVQBtAGsQChxENQBdGQBuU1MwPB4CFhIQYGl8olJKTgZZBgBqACIoZFFSVGZgOpUAbygBOsQcHA74XQEAJgBfcUyAemn4HNQ8wkLgNw8vKiFFFS2xeAAfeFRkYl0QGAyLU2XSYAA6AHcACxwAaVQcB44peAB2dPgsyOOAw8FEcCgoMAvBuAOR2sgs8lAIA8oBQ2DQBgB5GBkWAlSoCXYSaRyBjSKQ-Bp1eAAfngfQG1N6ulgdUyCNBNyKoxKXIqSJRaIxOGxuJgXR69P6gxUI3gEympiBHNKK1GAk60sJCj2h2Op3Ostg2uEuqOJzOMHG1wKt1Gd2lAKBRIO5oNMGGyFBDwQsQ+D3gWFBbBeyAgxTO8lNoju8EAfBuAdl3TEA)

Comment: Agree with @jcalz. In short, it can't be done nicely because you are creating a new type at runtime with a generic transformation.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since this question was discussed. Recently, I faced a similar task. Anyway, here is a possible solution with TS 4.1+

```
// helper types
type BaseT = Record<string, unknown> // object constraint
type BaseM = Record<string, string> // mapping constraint
type KVs<T extends BaseM> = keyof T | T[keyof T] // keys and values

type Remap<T extends BaseT, M extends BaseM> =
  & {[K in keyof M & keyof T as M[K]]: T[K]} // new keys
  & {[K in keyof T as Exclude<K, KVs<M>>]: T[K]} // unchanged keys

type Result = Remap<{a: 1; b: '2'}, {a: 'c'}>
// type Result = {b: '2'} & {c: 1}
```